# Problems using Spacy tokenizer with special characters

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, tokenize

I'm new to Spacy and I'm trying to find some patterns in a text, but I'm having trouble because of the form that tokenization works. For example, I have created the following pattern, trying to find percentage elements like "0,42%" using the Matcher (it's not exactly what I want, but I'm just practicing for now):

```
nlp = spacy.load("pt_core_news_sm")

matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)

text = 'total: 1,80%:(comex 1,30% + deriv 0,50%/ativo: 1,17% '

pattern_test =  [{"TEXT": {"REGEX": "[0-9]+[,.]+[0-9]+[%]"}}]  

text_ = nlp(text)

matcher.add("pattern test", [pattern_test] )
result = matcher(text_)

for id_, beg, end in result:
    print(id_)
    print(text_[beg:end])
```

The thing is that it is returning results like the one below, cause tokenization considers this as only one token:

```
9844711491635719110
1,80%:(comex
9844711491635719110
0,50%/ativo
```

I tried using Python's .replace() method on the string to replace special characters for blank spaces before tokenizing it, but now when I print the tokenization result it's separating everything like this:

```
text_adjustment = text.replace(":", " ").replace("(", " ").replace(")", " ").replace("/", " ").replace(";", " ").replace("-", " ").replace("+", " ")

print([token for token in text_adjustment])

['t', 'o', 't', 'a', 'l', ' ', ' ', '1', ',', '8', '0', '%', ' ', ' ', 'c', 'o', 'm', 'e', 'x', ' ', '1', ',', '3', '0', '%', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'd', 'e', 'r', 'i', 'v', ' ', '0', ',', '5', '0', '%', ' ', 'a', 't', 'i', 'v', 'o', ' ', ' ', '1', ',', '1', '7', '%', ' ']
```

I would like the tokenization result to be like that:

```
['total', '1,80%', 'comex', '1,30%', 'deriv', '0,50%', 'ativo', '1,17%']
```

Is there a better way to do that? I'm using the 'pt_core_news_sm' model, but I can change the language if I want to.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal reproducible example code?

Comment: sure! Just edited it

Comment: The regex inside patterns works on token level, and you can see that the document is tokenized like `['total', ':', '1,80%:(comex', '1,30', '%', '+', 'deriv', '0,50%/ativo', ':', '1,17', '%']`. Changing the model does not help, from what I see.

Comment: yes... what I was trying to do is to change the way the tokenizer works, so I could use regex properly. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: What if you insert spaces before the "glued" `/`, `(`, `)`  or `:`? Try `text = re.sub(r'(\S)([/:()])', r'\1 \2', text)` after `import re` and then `pattern_test =  [{"TEXT": {"REGEX": r"^\d+[,.]\d+$"}}, {"ORTH": "%"}]`

Comment: Well, you edited the question and now I am not sure why  you used matcher. Is the output a list of tokens?

Comment: my output are the percentages! I wrote the tokenization example just to show what I was trying to get by replacing the special characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using

```py
import re
#...
text = re.sub(r'(\S)([/:()])', r'\1 \2', text)
pattern_test =  [{"TEXT": {"REGEX": r"^\d+[,.]\d+$"}}, {"ORTH": "%"}]
```

Here, `(\S)([/:()])` regex is used to match any non-whitespace (capturing it into Group 1) and then matching a `/`, `:`, `(` or `)` (capturing it into Group 2) and then `re.sub` inserts a space between these two groups.

The `^\d+[,.]\d+$` regex matches a full token text that contains a float value and the `%` is the next token text (because the number and `%` are split into separate tokens by the model).

Full Python code snippet:

```py
import spacy, re
from spacy.matcher import Matcher

#nlp = spacy.load("pt_core_news_sm")
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_trf")
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
text = 'total: 1,80%:(comex 1,30% + deriv 0,50%/ativo: 1,17% '
text = re.sub(r'(\S)([/:()])', r'\1 \2', text)
pattern_test =  [{"TEXT": {"REGEX": "\d+[,.]\d+"}}, {"ORTH": "%"}]  
text_ = nlp(text)

matcher.add("pattern test", [pattern_test] )
result = matcher(text_)

for id_, beg, end in result:
    print(id_)
    print(text_[beg:end])
```

Output:

```py
9844711491635719110
1,80%
9844711491635719110
1,30%
9844711491635719110
0,50%
9844711491635719110
1,17%
```